# servicestack webservice testing with SOAPUI

Tags: servicestack, soapui

I have created a service using Service Stack  and would like to test it using SOAPUI. 
When I setup the SOAPUI project with the soap12 wsdl url [`http://<developmenturl>/soap12`], I keep getting the below error :

```
Mon Mar 13 15:14:29 GMT 2013:ERROR:Could not find element [{http://schemas.servicestack.net/types}<requestDTOobject>] specified in part [parameters]
```

Initially I had the DTO under a different name space, due to the above error message I changed the DTO object to be in the same namespace as the service
but still I get this error.

I have pasted below the request generated:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <typ:requestDTOtype/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear that SOAPUI is generating the correct request for ServiceStack. ServiceStack creates samples of the Soap1.2 requests and they can be found in  [metadata](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page) page (eg. `http://<developmenturl>/metadata`). To find the request for your 'Operation' click the SOAP 1.2 link to the right of it on the metadata page. You should be able to copy/replace this request into left pane of the SOAPUI request window.

**Sample of the HelloWorld SOAP 1.2 request**

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>

<HelloText xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HelloWorld">
  <Name>String</Name>
</HelloText>

    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way for soapui to automatically generate the request (as is typical) without having to copy and paste?  If I add the wsdl for soap12 (left hand of metadata page) it generates the soapui endpoints but without the params in the autogenerated request